# How can I sign a file with PKCS11 in Python?

Tags: python, django, token, digital-signature, pkcs#11

How can I sign a file with `PKCS11` in Python?

I'm looking for a way to sign a `.txt` file using a "Cryptographic Token Interface", but I haven't found a solution.

My first idea was to use `pycrypto`, but the documentation has no mention of this.

Comment: The main need of my application is the digital-signature by "Cryptographic Token Interface"...

For example, this is the line-code in Groovy that i would like know how to do in Django KeyStore pKstore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`pycrypto` is a low-level module that gives you all the pieces you need to build a cryptosystem, not a complete cryptosystem implementation.

Also, `pycrypto` doesn't have PKCS#11 support. And neither do the major alternatives. Even if you use one of the OpenSSL wrappers, normal builds of OpenSSL themselves don't have PKCS#11 support compiled in. You need to specify a .dll/.so/.dylib implementing PKCS#11 for your specific hardware (or multiple such libs) at configure time and build OpenSSL.

On top of that, if you're doing PKCS#11, one of the pieces you probably need is a way to interface with smartcards and other hardware token, and `pycrypto` doesn't do that part at all.

You may want to use a higher-level library, with hardware support built in, like [`pykcs11`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pykcs11). This wraps a C library that knows how to do both Windows built-in PKCS#11 and cross-platform PKCS#11, with a variety of different hardware from different vendors. Hopefully you can just use the high-level API; you may need to use the low-level API (or even combine two libraries—e.g., you might want to use `pykcs11` to generate a keypair, and then use `pycrypto` to sign something with the private key).

Comment: The examples that i found are not applicable for web (i may be wrong).
My coworker showed me how to do in `Groovy` (it's a possibility).
I'm seeking for a solution for web development

Comment: @Guilherme: If you need further help here, you're going to have to give us more information. Which examples are you talking about? How are they not applicable to web? What did your coworker show you in Groovy?

Comment: I should not have done the question with limited information, sorry.

The main need of my application is the `digital-signature` by "Cryptographic Token Interface"...

I would like to do in `Django`, needs to be a web application.

If i can't use django, i gonna start to study how to develop "web applications" in Groovy, cause my coworker had a way to resolve with 'java.security.KeyStore'

While i was looking the examples in the `pykcs11`, seemed to me a very specific script, mentioning DLLs and stuff like that.

Comment: For example, this is the line-code in `Groovy` that i would like know how to do in `Django`

`KeyStore pKstore = KeyStore.getInstance("Windows-MY", "SunMSCAPI");`

Comment: pycrypto does not wrap openssl in any way.

Answer (score 1):

[python-pkcs11](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-pkcs11) is what you want to use. There's documentation on [signing and verifying](http://python-pkcs11.readthedocs.io/en/latest/applied.html#signing-verifying).